# How to use shared_ptr in a decorator pattern implementation correctly?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, memory-leaks, decorator, shared-ptr

I am getting memory leak issues in the following code. I understand there are some flows. But not sure. How to use shared_ptr in these scenarios? And in case I need to add more decorators, say Chocolate-Pista-Icecream, how to pass the pointer correctly such that it will get deleted at the exit?

```
    class AbstractCream
{
public:
    virtual void ShowFlavour() = 0;
    virtual ~AbstractCream()
    {
        cout << endl << "AbstractCream-DTOR";
    }
};

class IceCream :public AbstractCream
{
public:
    void ShowFlavour()
    {
        cout << "IceCream";
    }
    ~IceCream()
    {
        cout << endl << "IceCream Dtor";
    }
};

class DecoratorCream :public AbstractCream
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<AbstractCream> AbCream;
public:
    DecoratorCream(std::shared_ptr<AbstractCream>abs) :AbCream(abs)
    {}
    void ShowFlavour()
    {
        AbCream->ShowFlavour();
    }
    virtual ~DecoratorCream()
    {
        cout << endl << "DecoratorCream-DTOR";

    }
};

class ChocolateCream : public DecoratorCream
{
public:
    ChocolateCream(std::shared_ptr<AbstractCream>abs) :DecoratorCream(abs)
    {}
    void ShowFlavour()
    {
        cout << "CholocateCream added..";
        DecoratorCream::ShowFlavour();
    }
    ~ChocolateCream()
    {
        cout << endl << "ChocolateCream-DTOR";
    }

};
class PistaCream : public DecoratorCream
{
public:
    PistaCream(std::shared_ptr<AbstractCream> abs) :DecoratorCream(abs)
    {}
    void ShowFlavour()
    {
        cout << "PistaCream added..";
        DecoratorCream::ShowFlavour();
    }
    ~PistaCream()
    {
        cout << endl << "PistaCream-DTOR";
    }
};

class StrawberryCream : public DecoratorCream
{
public:
    StrawberryCream(std::shared_ptr<AbstractCream> abs) :DecoratorCream(abs)
    {}
    void ShowFlavour()
    {
        cout << "StrawberryCream added..";
        DecoratorCream::ShowFlavour();
    }
    ~StrawberryCream()
    {
        cout << endl << "StrawberryCream-DTOR";
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr <AbstractCream> ice1( new IceCream());
    std::shared_ptr <PistaCream> pista1(new PistaCream(ice1));
    std::shared_ptr <AbstractCream> ice2(new IceCream());
    std::shared_ptr <ChocolateCream>choco1( new ChocolateCream(ice2));

    pista1->ShowFlavour();
    cout << endl;
    choco1->ShowFlavour();
    cout << endl;

    getchar();
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you should use `std::make_shared` and consider `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: could you elaborate on the above? My understanding is unique_ptr is useful if we have an array to clear similar or delete[];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem doesn't seem to be the `std::shared_ptr<...>` use in your classes: that seems to be semantically correct (it is too much code to review in detail, though). Instead, I think your `main()` is wrong: you try to determine memory leaks at point in time when the objects are still alive. I'm not a Windows program but I'm pretty sure that `_CrtDumpMemoryLeak()` doesn't know about `std::shared_ptr<...>` and simply reports `new`ed memory which isn't `delete`d, yet.

There are a couple of simply ways to change your `main()` to avoid the problem:

1. Put the allocation of objects into a block and report memory leaks after the block:

   ```
   int main() {
       {
           std::shared_ptr <AbstractCream> ice1( new IceCream());
           // ...
       }
       _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
   }
   ```
2. Put the code doing the actual work into a separate function and in `main()` just call this function and report on memory leaks:

   ```
   int actualMain() {
       std::shared_ptr <AbstractCream> ice1( new IceCream());
       // ...
   }
   int main() {
       int rc = actualMain();
       _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
   }
   ```
3. Report memory leaks from the destructor of an object which is constructed early, e.g., first thing in `main()`:

   ```
   struct Reporter { ~Reporter() { _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); } };
   int main() {
       Reporter reporter;
       std::shared_ptr <AbstractCream> ice1( new IceCream());
       // ...
   }
   ```

With all three approaches the `std::shared_ptr<...>`s are destroyed before memory leaks are reported. I'm pretty sure that all of these approaches make the memory leaks go away. My preference would be the use of the third approach.

That said, the way the `std::shared_ptr<...>` are passed isn't ideal from a performance point of view: increments the reference count each time. When passing it through multiple layers it is unnecessarily bumped up while calling and bumped down when returning from the call. There are multiple ways to fix that problem, too:

1. The simple approach is to pass the `std::shared_ptr<...>` as a constant reference:

   ```
   ChocolateCream(std::shared_ptr<AbstractCream> const& abs)
       : DecoratorCream(abs) {
   }
   ```
2. It can be argued that the pass by reference inhibits copy elision. However, argument construct can only be elided over one level: when passing the object on to another function it is a named object and the rules for copy elision allow eliding the copy from named objects only for `return` and `throw` statements. It may still be reasonable to go that route for the inner-most constructor. Even then, the `std::shared_ptr<...>` should be moved when passing it on (in that case to the construction of the member variable):

   ```
   DecoratorCream(std::shared_ptr<AbstractCream> abs)
       : AbCream(std::move(abs)) {
   }
   ```

   If you want to pass the argument by value in the other constructors, too, you should, at least, `std::move(...)` the argument. Doing so should avoid the reference count but it still won't avoid all work as it needs to construct/destroy a `std::shared_ptr<...>` on each level. However, at least, the synchronized maintenance of the reference count would be avoided.

Since I mentioned a performance problem: [stop using `std::endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/). It doesn't do you much good. In your use it just slows down the program.

Comment: @Dietman: Thank you very much for the help. That solved the memory check. It in fact clearing the memory, but the check-point was wrong as you said. The second point , of std::endl. What could be the better alternatives just to print after new line? Last but not least, I am still not able to pass nested new pointers to outer shared pointer. I need to create one first with another shared pointer, then have to pass that to another to get more number of wraps (in case of Decorator). Is this exprected?

Comment: /*Below code sample to show how I have to try three layers of decoration*/std::shared_ptr <AbstractCream> ice2(new IceCream());
 std::shared_ptr <ChocolateCream>choco1( new ChocolateCream(ice2));
 std::shared_ptr <StrawberryCream>straw1(new StrawberryCream(choco1));

Comment: @Anand: re `std::endl`: just use `'\n'`. If you follow the [link](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/) from the answer you'll find a reasonably thorough write-up of the reasoning and the alternatives. re the needed objects: I'm not particular good at object-oriented programming but I think it is to be expected that you'd have the objects being decorated around.

Comment: @Dietman: thank you. Now I get the reason to avoid std::endl.

Answer (score 1):

```
class AbstractCream
{
public:
    virtual void ShowFlavour() = 0;
    virtual ~AbstractCream()
    {
        cout << endl << "AbstractCream-DTOR";
    }
};

class IceCream :public AbstractCream
{
public:
    void ShowFlavour()
    {
        cout << "IceCream";
    }
    ~IceCream()
    {
        cout << endl << "IceCream Dtor";
    }
};

class DecoratorCream :public AbstractCream
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<AbstractCream> AbCream;
public:
    DecoratorCream(const std::shared_ptr<AbstractCream> &abs) :AbCream(abs)
    {}
    void ShowFlavour()
    {
        AbCream->ShowFlavour();
    }
    virtual ~DecoratorCream()
    {
        cout << endl << "DecoratorCream-DTOR";

    }
};

class ChocolateCream : public DecoratorCream
{
public:
    ChocolateCream(const std::shared_ptr<AbstractCream>& abs) :DecoratorCream(abs)
    {}
    void ShowFlavour()
    {
        cout << "CholocateCream added..";
        DecoratorCream::ShowFlavour();
    }
    ~ChocolateCream()
    {
        cout << endl << "ChocolateCream-DTOR";
    }

};
class PistaCream : public DecoratorCream
{
public:
    PistaCream(const std::shared_ptr<AbstractCream> &abs) :DecoratorCream(abs)
    {}
    void ShowFlavour()
    {
        cout << "PistaCream added..";
        DecoratorCream::ShowFlavour();
    }
    ~PistaCream()
    {
        cout << endl << "PistaCream-DTOR";
    }
};

class StrawberryCream : public DecoratorCream
{
public:
    StrawberryCream(const std::shared_ptr<AbstractCream>& abs) :DecoratorCream(abs)
    {}
    void ShowFlavour()
    {
        cout << "StrawberryCream added..";
        DecoratorCream::ShowFlavour();
    }
    ~StrawberryCream()
    {
        cout << endl << "StrawberryCream-DTOR";
    }
};


//-------------------dec--------------------------------------------------------------//
struct DummyToLeakCheck
{
public:
    ~DummyToLeakCheck()
    {
        _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    }
};
int main()
{
    DummyToLeakCheck myLeakChecker;
    std::shared_ptr <AbstractCream> ice1( new IceCream());
    std::shared_ptr <PistaCream> pista1(new PistaCream(ice1));
    std::shared_ptr <AbstractCream> ice2(new IceCream());
    std::shared_ptr <ChocolateCream>choco1( new ChocolateCream(ice2));
    std::shared_ptr <StrawberryCream>straw1(new StrawberryCream(choco1));

    pista1->ShowFlavour();
    cout << endl;
    choco1->ShowFlavour();
    cout << endl;
    straw1->ShowFlavour();
    cout << endl;

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Using a Leak-checker as mentioned in the first answer helped correcting the original code.Modified code. Ignoring std::endl as of now, since the purpose of the code is to try out smart pointers in decorator pattern.